# show/hide th/td in angular dependent on button click without changing table width

Tags: angularjs

I have a **Show All** or **Show Me** button which toggles `vm.todoShowAll` with true or false.

This is my controller code:

```
var vm = this;
vm.init = function() {
    vm.todoShowAll   = false;
    vm.myName        = "Torben";
}

vm.showTodo = function () {
    vm.todoShowAll = !vm.todoShowAll;
    return false;
}
```

When Its **false** I want to show only my ToDo tasks where `todos.name==vm.myName` and hide the name column in the table

When Its **true** I want to show all ToDo tasks and show the name column in the table

...and of cause without the table changing shape

Unfortunately this is how it looks now:

[image]

I dont know how to filter / unfilter, and I dont know how to avoid the table changing width.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="start-todo start-todo-table start-todo-hover" ng-if="vm.todo.length > 0">
<thead>
    <tr class="start-header start-bold start-todo-bg">
        <th colspan="6" class="start-padding overflow start-left">
           ToDo List
            <a ng-click="vm.showTodo()" ng-hide="vm.todoShowAll">
                <button class="start-todo-btn start-button" style="width:80px; margin-left:5px;">SHOW ALL</button>
            </a>
            <a ng-click="vm.showTodo()" ng-show="vm.todoShowAll">
                <button class="start-todo-btn start-button" style="width:80px; margin-left:5px;">SHOW ME</button>
            </a>
            <a ui-sref="book()">
                <button class="start-todo-btn start-button" style="width:80px;">NEW TODO</button>
            </a>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="start-header start-head start-todo-bg">
        <th class="start-left nowrap" style="min-width:66px;">Property</th>
        <th class="start-left overflow" style="width:18%">Category</th>
        <th class="start-left overflow" style="width:45%">Task</th>
        <th class="start-left overflow" style="width:15%">Time</th>
        <th class="start-right overflow" style="width:10%">Day</th>
        <th class="start-left overflow" style="width:15%" ng-show="vm.todoShowAll">Name</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="todos in vm.todo | orderBy:'days'" class="start-text">
        <td class="start-left start-border nowrap">{{ todos.property }}</td>
        <td class="start-left start-border start-smaller overflow">{{ todos.todoCategory }}</td>
        <td class="start-left start-border overflow">{{ todos.task }}</td>
        <td class="start-left start-border overflow">{{ todos.time }}</td>
        <td class="start-right start-border overflow start-bold greennum">
            <span ng-class="(todo.days) > 0 ? 'greennum' : 'rednum'"><b>{{todos.days}}</b></span>
        </td>
        <td class="start-left start-border overflow" ng-show="vm.todoShowAll">{{ todos.name }}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter your columns, you can add a filter to the ng-repeat directive. That would look like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="todos in vm.todo | filter:vm.nameFilter | orderBy:'days'" class="start-text">
..
</tr>
```

then in your controller, you can add the filter function like this:

```
vm.nameFilter = function(item){
    return vm.todoShowAll || item.name === vm.myName;
}
```

To have the tables have the same width, simply add a `width: 100%` style to your `start-todo-table` class:

```
.start-todo-table {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Nikolaj du er for vild!! :-D  It worked perfectly.  (needed a | in the `filter:vm.nameFilter | orderBy:'days'` but now everything works great, also the table. Thanks a lot!!! (hvis du nogen sinde er i thailand så kig forbi os)